# What is the difference between main-page.js and main-view.model.js when developing native apps through Telerik App Builder

Tags: javascript, telerik, nativescript, telerik-appbuilder, nativescript-telerik-ui

How to change the text of the xml based textField via main-page.js? Im using `this.set("message", getMessage(this.counter));` to change the values via main-view-model.js. But that scenario is not working when I try in it in main-page.js. How to do this? :-) And I need an explanation to my main question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you talking about the "Hello World" NativeScript application that can be found [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/template-hello-world). The difference is that the [**main-page.js**](https://github.com/NativeScript/template-hello-world/blob/master/main-page.js) is the "*code behind*" of the [**main-page.xml**](https://github.com/NativeScript/template-hello-world/blob/master/main-page.xml) (note that naming convention is important for {N} to make the match) and the main-view-model.js is a separate file which has been assigned as `bindingContext` to the Page of the main-page.xml in its navigatingTo event as you can see [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/template-hello-world/blob/master/main-page.js#L32):

```
function onNavigatingTo(args) {
    /*
    This gets a reference this page’s <Page> UI component. You can
    view the API reference of the Page to see what’s available at
    https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_page_.page.html
    */
    var page = args.object;

    /*
    A page’s bindingContext is an object that should be used to perform
    data binding between XML markup and JavaScript code. Properties
    on the bindingContext can be accessed using the {{ }} syntax in XML.
    In this example, the {{ message }} and {{ onTap }} bindings are resolved
    against the object returned by createViewModel().
    You can learn more about data binding in NativeScript at
    https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding.
    */
    page.bindingContext = createViewModel();
}
```

In order to change the text of the Label (TextView) of the main-page.xml in its code behind file you could ether get the Label via an id (`getViewById()` [example](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/basics#execute-business-logic)) or directly use the `bindingContext` (your 'ViewModel'):

```
var createViewModel = require("./main-view-model").createViewModel;
var viewModel;

function onNavigatingTo(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    viewModel = = createViewModel();
    page.bindingContext = viewModel;
}

// Example with event handler for a 'tap' event of a Button
function onButtonTap(args) {
    viewModel.set("message", "New message set via code behind");
}
```